# SQL Joining multiple tables with aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody explain, joins with multiple tables with aliases?

I can't get the code to work... keep giving me errors with "Could not be bound" this error message is for the following: M.ZipCode, C.Member_ID, F.Navn, F.Navn (the last one).
I'm still quite new to SQL, and I know I have messed up with the Zipcode names.
to clarify I have a table, called Zipcode that holds Zipcodes, and members require a zipcode in the members table.

```
SELECT
  m.Fornavn,
  m.Efternavn,
  m.Zipcode,
  z.City,
  c.Model,
  c.Producent,
  s.Navn,
  s.Antal,
  s.Pris
FROM Members M, Fabricator F, Cars C, Storage S, ZipCode Z
  INNER JOIN Members ON Z.Zipcode = M.ZipCode AND C.Member_ID = Members.ID
  INNER JOIN Cars ON F.Navn = Cars.Producent
  INNER JOIN Storage ON F.Navn = Storage.Producent;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You are mixing SQL'89 and SQL'92 syntax for the same unions. You either use explicit Joins (preferred) or you don't use JOINs and set the union conditions on the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would appear to want the following `FROM` clause:

```
FROM ZipCode z INNER JOIN
     Members m
     ON z.Zipcode = m.ZipCode INNER JOIN
     Cars c
     ON c.Member_ID = m.ID INNER JOIN
     Fabricator f
     ON f.Navn = c.Producent INNER JOIN
     Storage s
     ON f.Navn = s.Producent
```

The comma in the `FROM` clause means `CROSS JOIN` -- a Cartesian product.  You have the same tables mentioned multiple times.  The simplest approach is to learn to use the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean

```
SELECT
m.Fornavn,
m.Efternavn,
m.Zipcode,
z.City,
c.Model,
c.Producent,
s.Navn,
s.Antal,
s.Pris 
FROM Fabricator F
INNER JOIN Cars C ON F.Navn = C.Producent
INNER JOIN Members M ON C.Member_ID = M.ID
INNER JOIN ZipCode Z  ON Z.Zipcode = M.ZipCode
INNER JOIN Storage S ON F.Navn = S.Producent
```

Answer (score 0):

> FROM Members M, Fabricator F, Cars C, Storage S, ZipCode Z

is a short form of CROSS JOIN, so you have to avoid this notation and as far as I know it is deprecated notation